# cons return a list and pair in scheme

Tags: scheme

I just started to learn scheme. My question is why does `(cons 3 (4))` return a list `(3 4)` but `(cons (4) 3)` returns a pair `((4) . 3)`? should `(cons 3 (4))` returns `(3 . (4))` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `(3 4)` and `(3. (4))`are the list `(cons 3 (cons 4 '())))`, and if you enter `'(3 . (4))` in your REPL, you will most likely see `'(3 4)` as the result.

The difference you're seeing is just an output convention; a pair where the `cdr` is a list is not printed with dot notation.